# What type of cast does *( char** ) achieve?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, function-pointers, dereference

What type of cast does `*( char** )` accomplish?
It seems to create a pointer to a pointer ("double pointer") with the `**`. But the `*` outside the parentheses confuses me... Below is the cast in context:

```
void mem_test ( void )
{
    void* m1;
    void* m2;

    ...

    m1 = 0;

    while ( ( m2 = malloc( 10001 ) ) != 0 )
    {
        *( char** ) m2 = m1;  // what does this cast mean?

        m1 = m2;
    }

    ...
}
```

Another confusing variant of it appears in the following snippet. What does the cast accomplish in this scenario, and is it different from the one above?

```
void mpenter ( void );  // a function with no parameters and no return value

...

uchar* code;

...

*( void ( ** ) ( void ) ) ( code - 8 ) = mpenter;  // what does this cast mean?
```

---

What is the proper name for this type of cast? I.e. what should I be searching for to learn more about it?

Comment: I would search for "... and that's how I failed my code review..." :)

Comment: It’s not part of the cast. It’s a separate dereference. Have you seen `*ptr = 5;`? Like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `mem_test`

Let's dissect this step-by-step.  To make it easy, assume we're on a 64-bit architecture where pointers are 8 bytes in size.

- `m2 = malloc( 10001 )` assigns `m2` to a freshly allocated block of memory.
- `(char **) m2` says "let's pretend the first 8 bytes of memory at address `m2` is a `char*`, and point at **that** -- resulting in a `char**`"
- `*(char **) m2` dereferences the above, resulting in an l-value to a `char*` (in C speak).  Remember l-values are writable.

  - in C++, it would result in a reference to a `char*`, i.e. `char*&`
- `*(char **) m2 = m1;` writes the value of `m1` into the l-value created above.

Another way to write that code would be:

```
char* pCurrentBuffer;
char* pPreviousBuffer;

pPreviousBuffer = NULL;
while ( ( pCurrentBuffer = malloc( 10001 ) ) != NULL )
{
    char** ppPreviousBuffer = (char**)pCurrentBuffer;
    *ppPreviousBuffer = pPreviousBuffer;

    pPreviousBuffer = pCurrentBuffer;
}
```

Surprise(!), in the end, it creates a linked list.  (technically it's a reversed linked-list because they are all previous pointers instead of next pointers, but I am joking)

### `mpenter`

This is casting the 8 bytes at address `code - 8` to a pointer-to-function-pointer, so that it can assign the address of function `mpenter` into that location.

- `void (*)(void)` is a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns `void`.
- By extension, `void (**)(void)` is a pointer to a function-pointer of the above type.
- Dereferencing that yields an l-value to a function-pointer.

  - In C++ it would create a reference to a function-pointer, if that's easier to reason about.
- Assigning it writes the address of `mpenter` into that l-value (i.e. the 8 bytes of memory at address `code - 8`)

It's unusual to take a negative offset from a pointer, but if `code` is pointing into the middle of a struct of some kind, it may be legitimate (in some loose sense of the word).

Comment: "PS: This code really made me laugh. As did Retired Ninja's comment." Not sure I understand the humor or @retired-ninja's remark...Is it because the code snippets do not seem to be doing anything useful, or is it my confusion with the pointer syntax... If it's the former, the code snippets are little chunks from a much bigger program ([one](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/main.c), [two](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/usertests.c)). If it's the latter, I am more familiar with higher level languages that hide away pointers...

Comment: The code snippets were doing things in a very roundabout fashion, and they are not typesafe.  Most people would create a struct Node { Node* pNext; }; to define a linked list.  (FWIW not poking fun at you -- I don't blame anyone for being puzzled at this code; I was too)

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't understand the syntax/grammar, let alone what the logic was trying to do. The logic could have been finding a solution to world peace and I wouldn't have a clue =)

Comment: Could the snippets have equivalently been written as `*(   ( char** ) m2   )` and `*(   ( void ( ** ) ( void ) ) ( code - 8 )   )`? Where the outer parenthesis helps to visually separate the casting from the dereferencing `*( (cast)x )`... Or does the added outer parenthesis change the meaning/logic? Using a temporary variable as you do is much more readable, but curious if an additional set of parenthesis as shown can be used to slightly improve legibility.

Comment: Also, I assume the ultimate address would be different if it was `(cast)code - 4` vs `(cast)(code - 4)` because of pointer arithmetic...Is this correct? In the former case it would be `-(4*(sizeof(cast_type)))`, and the latter case just plain old `-4`?

Comment: The additional outer parentheses you wrote as in `*( ( char** ) m2 )` are certainly valid and do not change the logic.  I have worked in codebases where `*( _thing_ )` was the coding standard =)

Comment: Also totally correct on the `(cast)code - 4` versus `(cast)(code - 4)` due to pointer arithmetic.